# Error cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataToUpload>' to 'DataToUpload[]'

Tags: c#, typeerror

I have a web service which accepts list of object/class as input parameter. Below is my web service code :

```
[WebMethod]
public string LoadContacts(List<DataToUpload> objData)
{..}
public class DataToUpload
{..}
```

I need to consume this web service in windows c# application. I called the `Loadcontacts` method as follows:

```
WebReferance.DataUploadToAltitude obj = new WebReferance.DataUploadToAltitude();
List<WebReferance.DataToUpload> cls_list = new List<WebReferance.DataToUpload>();
..
label1.Text = obj.LoadContacts(cls_list);
```

This code throws the error shown below:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'WindowsFormsApplication1.WebReferance.DataToUpload[]'
>
> The best overloaded method match for 'WindowsFormsApplication1.WebReferance.DataUploadToAltitude.LoadContacts(WindowsFormsApplication1.WebReferance.DataToUpload[])' has some invalid arguments

Why is it accepting the array when my web service accepts List?

Answer (score 0):

By default you cannot pass lists to a Web Service call, if your webservice accepts or returns a list<> (or any collection), it will actually be expecting or return an array. You can change the collection type when you add the service to your project.

I recommend just converting into arrays, or use a newer technology such as webAPI or WCF.